# Algorithm To Make Best Use of Multiple Linear Container Space

Tags: algorithm

I have a set number of equal sized linear "containers." For this example say I have 10 containers that can hold up to a maximum value of 28. These containers are filled serially with incoming objects of varying values. The objects will have a known minimum and maximum value, for this example the minimum would be 3.5 and the maximum 15. The objects can be any size between this minimum and maximum. The items leave the containers in an unknown order. If there is not enough room in any of the containers for the next incoming object it is rejected.

I am looking for an algorithm that utilizes the container space the most efficiently and minimizes the amount of rejected objects.

Comment: What goes wrong with your algorithm?

Comment: What class is this for?

Comment: Currently I am loading each container up until (container size - maximum object size) to save enough space in each container for the possible largest object. This is working fairly well but I am hoping to find something more efficient if possible.

Comment: This sounds isomorphic to the well known "bin packing problem".

Comment: @clwhisk This is not.  In the well known "bin packing problem" you know the objects in advance.  In this one you have to put each one in as it arrives.  It is complex and specific enough that I suspect that it is based on a real world logistics problem.

Comment: Still, if that is the only difference OP can google "online bin packing problem" and find many algorithms and approaches. @btilly e.g. [my second hit](http://math.haifa.ac.il/lea/rwor_bp.pdf)

Comment: Yes, this is based on a real world logistics problem. Investigating the bin packing problem I could not find much for a constant incoming outgoing stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute best solution will depend on the actual sizes, distribution of incoming objects, and so on.  I would strongly recommend setting up realistic distributions that you experience in the real world as test code, and trying out different algorithms against it.

The obvious heuristic that I would want to try is to always put each object in the fullest bin that it can fit in.

Comment: I am working on setting up a simulation with sample distributions. I am looking for suggestions on different algorithms to try out. Thanks for yours!